# Uploading file using libcurl failed. Uploading speed is zero

Tags: c++, file-upload, libcurl

Edit: This upload-file-thing is really killing me! I've no idea why this code doesn't work. It's published at libcurl-website. It's supposed to be right. Could anyone help me plz!

I'm testing the fileupload.c from code examples found at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fileupload.html
However, I can't upload a txt to server. 
I replaced the origin code

```
 fd = fopen("debugit", "rb"); /* open file to upload */ 
 /* upload to this place */ 
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
                 "file:///home/dast/src/curl/debug/new");
```

to

```
  fd = fopen("c:\\\testupload.txt", "rb"); 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
                 "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/dir/test.txt");
```

Here's the output.  See bottom: Speed: 0.000 bytes/sec during 0.120 seconds.

```
----------

C:\>"MyProjects\libcurl\VC6\Upload\Debug\Upload.exe"

* About to connect() to xx.xx.xx.xx port 80 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx... * connected
* Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> PUT /dir/testupload.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 8600
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Sun, 24 Aug 2014 21:51:21 GMT
< Content-Length: 5184
<
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/x
html1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;back
ground:#CBE1EF;}
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;}
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;}
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;}
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 40px;}
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;}
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;}
legend{color:#333333;padding:4px 15px 4px 10px;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-to
p:0px;
 border-top:1px solid #EDEDED;border-left:1px solid #EDEDED;border-right:1px sol
id #969696;
 border-bottom:1px solid #969696;background:#E7ECF0;font-weight:bold;font-size:1
em;}
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;}
a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;}
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0;
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet M
S",Verdana,sans-serif;
 color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2;
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;p
adding:10px;position:relative;}
.config_source{background:#fff5c4;}
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0;
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%;
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden;
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:1
1px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF;
 background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #
4A6C8E;font-weight:normal;
 font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right;
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;}
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;}
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:bold;border:n
one;}
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:normal;}
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%;
}#details-right th{width:20%;}
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{background-color:#ebebeb;}
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;}
.clear{clear:both;}
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FF
F;font-size:.8em;}
-->
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error in Application "PP"</h1></div>
<div id="server_version"><p>Internet Information Services 7.5</p></div>
<div id="content">
<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><legend>Error Summary</legend>
  <h2>HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, o
r is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><legend>Detailed Error Information</legend>
  <div id="details-left">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>IIS Web Core</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Notification</th><td>MapRequestHandler</td></tr>
    <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>StaticFile</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>0x80070002</td></tr>

   </table>
  </div>
  <div id="details-right">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>http://192.168.0.135:80/wonderful/
testupload.txt</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>E:\phpsite\wonderful\testupload.txt</td></tr>

    <tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>Anonymous</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>Anonymous</td></tr>

   </table>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><legend>Most likely causes:</legend>
  <ul>  <li>The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.</l
i>      <li>The URL contains a typographical error.</li>        <li>A custom fil
ter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.</li> </ul>
 </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><legend>Things you can try:</legend>
  <ul>  <li>Create the content on the Web server.</li>  <li>Review the browser U
RL.</li>        <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP
 status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information abo
ut creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microso
ft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul>
 </fieldset>
</div>


<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><legend>Links and More Information</legend>
  This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Crea
te the file or directory and try the request again.
  <p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=404,0,
0x80070002,7600">View more information &raquo;</a></p>

 </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host xx.xx.xx.xx left intact
Speed: 0.000 bytes/sec during 0.120 seconds
* Closing connection #0

C:\>
```

Comment: You got a 404 back, quite clearly the server doesn't like your request to that URL.

Comment: @DanielStenberg How can I fix that?

Comment: Change the URL to something more appropriate (probably starting with `http:`) and learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: We can't tell you what server you have nor what URL that server would have that accepts a PUT, that's your job to find out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default setting of my server does accept PUT and POST method. But I have to write an asp or php code to receive the data and then put data to a txt.